# смена URL у картинки с эфектом

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Есть картинка, после нажатия на кнопку картинка меняет URL. Все пашет, но охота плавной смены картинки одной на другую. Решений полно, но все они сводятся к листанию тегов `<li>` `<img>`.

Можно ли сменить URL у картинки, так что бы на экране смена была плавная?

Js:

```
 $("#main_foto").attr("src",newurl);
```

Comment: решение плавно скрыть элемент -> заменить урл -> показать элемент не подходит? Например методом fadeOut и fadeIn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делаем эффект исчезновения, изменяем URL изображения, делаем эффект появления:

```
 $('#someButton').click(function() {
    $('#main_foto')
      .fadeOut('slow')
      .delay(1000, function() {
         $("#main_foto").attr("src",newurl)
         .fadeIn(600);
      });
  });
```